# How to add IAM conditions in gcp request for the TestIamPermissions API in golang?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, identity-management, gcp-iam

I'm trying to test permissions with the TestIamPermissions API provided by GCP, my permissions are scoped by IAM conditions, but as I see in gcp documentation, this API gets resource and TestIamPermissionsRequest as parameters,

This is how I use it for now in my code without the IAM conditions

```
var response *cloudresourcemanager.TestIamPermissionsResponse
            if err = apiRetryBackoff(func() error {
                response, err = c.projectsService.TestIamPermissions(check.projectID, &cloudresourcemanager.TestIamPermissionsRequest{Permissions: check.requiredPermissions}).Do()
                return err
            }); err != nil {
                return err
            }
```

And these are the documetations from gcp package code

```
// TestIamPermissions: Returns permissions that a caller has on the
// specified Project. For additional information about `resource` (e.g.
// my-project-id) structure and identification, see Resource Names
// (https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names). There are no
// permissions required for making this API call.
//
// - resource: REQUIRED: The resource for which the policy detail is
//   being requested. See the operation documentation for the
//   appropriate value for this field.
func (r *ProjectsService) TestIamPermissions(resource string, testiampermissionsrequest *TestIamPermissionsRequest) *ProjectsTestIamPermissionsCall {
    c := &ProjectsTestIamPermissionsCall{s: r.s, urlParams_: make(gensupport.URLParams)}
    c.resource = resource
    c.testiampermissionsrequest = testiampermissionsrequest
    return c
}
```

```
// TestIamPermissionsRequest: Request message for `TestIamPermissions`
// method.
type TestIamPermissionsRequest struct {
    // Permissions: The set of permissions to check for the `resource`.
    // Permissions with wildcards (such as '*' or 'storage.*') are not
    // allowed. For more information see IAM Overview
    // (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#permissions).
    Permissions []string `json:"permissions,omitempty"`

    // ForceSendFields is a list of field names (e.g. "Permissions") to
    // unconditionally include in API requests. By default, fields with
    // empty or default values are omitted from API requests. However, any
    // non-pointer, non-interface field appearing in ForceSendFields will be
    // sent to the server regardless of whether the field is empty or not.
    // This may be used to include empty fields in Patch requests.
    ForceSendFields []string `json:"-"`

    // NullFields is a list of field names (e.g. "Permissions") to include
    // in API requests with the JSON null value. By default, fields with
    // empty values are omitted from API requests. However, any field with
    // an empty value appearing in NullFields will be sent to the server as
    // null. It is an error if a field in this list has a non-empty value.
    // This may be used to include null fields in Patch requests.
    NullFields []string `json:"-"`
}
```

I would be happy to get more explanation about how IAM gcp conditions can be tested ?

I tried to add the condition to the request with no success